# Unlock encrypted disk with hardware key

Tags: grub2, encryption, luks

**Desired Solution**

I want to be able to use a hardware key to unlock the encrypted disc on my computer. In the current situation I have to enter a password to unlock the disc and continue booting. In the new situation I want to insert a hardware key instead of entering a password and continue booting.

By hardware key I mean something like YubiKey, SoloKey, etc. .

**Question**

As far as I can tell I should just install Ubuntu 20.4 LTS with disc encryption. This way I will have a disc encrypted with LUKS2.

Can somebody confirm that Ubuntu 20.4 LTS runs LUKS2?
Can somebody confirm that I can use a hardware key to unlock the disc and continue booting?

**Conflicting information**

According to this [guide](http://0pointer.net/blog/unlocking-luks2-volumes-with-tpm2-fido2-pkcs11-security-hardware-on-systemd-248.html) you can use a hardware key to unlock a disc that was encrypted using LUKS2. This [post](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=GRUB-Boots-LUKS2-Disk-Encrypt) tells me that GRUB supports LUKS2. But this [post](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Full_Disk_Encryption_Howto_2019) says that GRUB does not support LUKS2:

> The default LUKS (Linux Unified Key Setup) format (version) used by
> the cryptsetup tool has changed since the release of 18.04 Bionic.
> 18.04 used version 1 ("luks1") but more recent Ubuntu releases default to version 2 ("luks2"). GRUB only supports opening version 1 so we
> have to explicitly set luks1 in the commands we use or else GRUB will
> not be able to install to, or unlock, the encrypted device.

Comment: Yes LUKS is perfect for disk encryption.  How about a TPM?

Comment: Also this question has already been answered in terms of yubikey access..

https://askubuntu.com/questions/599825/yubikey-two-factor-authentication-full-disk-encryption-via-luks?rq=1