# Encrypt hard disc on ubuntu server 18.04 with luks and yubikey

Tags: server, 18.04, luks, yubikey

This https://askubuntu.com/a/599826/1068251 do not work for ubuntu server 18.04.
Ubuntu ask about touching yubikey and repeat again question. I can login only with passphrase.

I found other solution github.
https://github.com/carniz/ubuntu-yubikey-setup

Can I try method from github? Is that secure?

Regards

Comment: Not an answer to this problem but something you need to be aware of Ubuntu 18.04 goes EOL at the end of May. Time to upgrade while there is still full support.

Comment: [Ubuntu 18.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/05/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-begins-31-may-2023/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 18.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com//blog/18-04-end-of-standard-support

Comment: @guiverc 18.04 was not EoL when the question was asked, so the question is not off-topic for this reason. We should not retroactively close questions as off-topic because the release they ask about has gone EoL.

Comment: @David You have right I swaped it.